# Run jinja2 template_filter on every request using Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I generate URLs with a `jinja2` `template_filter` using `Flask`:

```
@app.template_filter()
def generate_stuff(url):
    return do_stuff(url)
```

This template_filter is only executed once per URL. If a user reloads the page I want `Flask` to run this function, again. How do I do this?

PS: I am new to `Flask`. If there is a better way to achieve the same I am also interested, of course :)

Comment: If the user reloads the page the template filter will be re-run, because the `render_template` call will be run again.  Can you give us some more details as to what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Template filters](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#registering-filters) are the wrong thing to use here, those are for adding extra functions you can use against variables in templates.  You're probably looking for [context processors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#context-processors).  You can use [`request.url`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.path) to get the url, or there are other path properties on request as well if that's not what you want.

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_user():
    return {
        'my_stuff': do_stuff(request.url)
    }
```