# Parse url with jinja

Tags: python-2.7, templates, flask, jinja2

In jinja, I can do `{{request.path}}` to get the url.
However, i have a token, that is dynamic, so i can't check the entire url.

```
/users/review/step2/c/DqBJjAZ4PdmpfhzbXBc5g9
/users/review/step2/u/DqBJjAZ4PdmpfhzbXBc5g9
```

My question is about identify the part with `/c/` or `/u/`. c is create and u update.

After that i can build an `url_for` using `c` or `u` accordingly the url. What is the best way to identify if the url is to create or update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest just passing a variable to your template to be used in the template.

so

```
@app.route('/users/review/step2/c/<token>')
def if_template(token):
    return render_template(
        "template.jinja2",
        create=True)

@app.route('/users/review/step2/u/<token>')
def if_template(token):
    return render_template(
        "template.jinja2",
        update=True)
```

if you're only two states are create and update than one variable will probably suffice.

Comment: I am thinking about app template_filter to parse the url, but probably your answer makes more sense. thanks

Comment: [If you want to go down that route I'd actually suggest using context_processors.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151680/run-jinja2-template-filter-on-every-request-using-flask) In fact [using a context_processor would allow you to do the url parsing and pass that directly into your template](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#context-processors)